# Condtionally create a folder in InstallShield 2010

Tags: windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2010

I am using InstallShield 2010 to build an installer for our product (yes I know it's out of date and I'm trying to get the upgrade but for now this is what I have).

One of the things the installer needs to do is create a directory for storing data. But I only want to create that directory if a certain combination of features are selected (basically, one feature should be selected and two others should not).

I created the folder in the Files and Folder view, but I don't see how to create it conditionally. I tried associating the component to the feature that should be selected, and setting as a condition of the component that the other two features are not selected, but this didn't work. The folder is still created every time the associated feature is selected, regardless of whether the other two features are selected or not.

I suppose I could create it within an if statement using InstallScript, but I'd rather do it from the InstallShield GUI, if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. FeatureStates aren't evaluated until Costing, and by that point the component list is set.

You need to do it in a custom action; either installscript, vbscript, MSI Dll, etc. and use the feature states you care about as a condition on the custom action.

Comment: Thanks. Putting it in a custom action with conditions worked.